# Convert HTML to PDF with HTML_ToPDF class (PHP)

Tags: php, pdf-generation, debian

In my project, I'm using [HTML_ToPDF](http://rustyparts.com/pdf.php) PHP class, which uses [html2ps](http://user.it.uu.se/~jan/html2ps.html) script to convert from HTML to PDF file.

Recently I upgraded my production server to Debian 5 (Lenny) and, after that, `HTML_ToPDF` is no longer working:

`convert()` method from `HTML_ToPDF` class is returning this error:

```
Error: there was a problem running the html2ps command.  Error code returned: 127.  setDebug() for more information.
```

And, the output from html2ps call is:

```
/usr/bin/perl: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/perl5/auto/Compress/Zlib/Zlib.so: undefined symbol: Perl_Tstack_sp_ptr
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

**[Edited]**
After some tests, I've found that the problem happens only with HTML containing images ( tags). When html2ps founds the first image it crashes. Converting HTML without images works fine. Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

apt-get install perl=5.8.8-7etch6 perl-base=5.8.8-7etch6 perl-modules=5.8.8-7etch6 debconf-i18n=1.5.11etch2 liblocale-gettext-perl=1.05-1 libtext-iconv-perl=1.4-3 libtext-wrapi18n-perl=0.06-5 libtext-charwidth-perl=0.04-4 html2ps=1.0b5-2 libapache2-mod-perl2=2.0.2-2.4 libcompress-zlib-perl=1.42-2 libfuse-perl=0.07-2+b2 libhtml-parser-perl=3.55-1 libhtml-tree-perl=3.19.01-2 libio-zlib-perl=1.04-1 libwww-perl=5.805-1 perlmagick=7:6.2.4.5.dfsg1-0.14 snmpd=5.2.3-7etch4 xhtml2ps mysql-client=5.0.32-7etch8 mysql-client-5.0=5.0.32-7etch8 libdbd-mysql-perl=3.0008-1 libdbi-perl=1.53-1etch1

http://www.deberias.com

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the initial conversion from HTML to PS. Usually due to poorly written HTML.

Can you show some examples of what you are trying to convert?

Comment: Sorry, I can't do it due to security reasons. Yes, my HTML is a little poorly written but, trust me, in this case the HTML is not the problem: before Debian update, it was working with same HTML and without problems. 

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I've found [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) to be far better than html2ps, even though it's at a fairly early stage of development.

I wrote [a blog about it](http://ciaranmcnulty.com/blog/2009/04/converting-html-to-pdf-using-wkhtmltopdf), but if you don't want to read that basically it uses KHTML/Webkit's rendering engine to render the page which is a bit more sensible than the usual approach of writing a complete HTML renderer.

The distributed binary worked just fine on my Debian server, and frankly the results are excellent.

Comment: I've read your blog and it seems interesting, but to need a X server scares me a bit, my production server's CPU is high loaded.

Thanks anyway!

Comment: It is a worry, but it's only a 'temporary' X-server and isn't using a huge framebuffer - I'd have to do some profiling vs. html2ps before I assumed it was more impact.  Thanks for the click though!